# Image Identification Using CIDetector iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to identify an image already stored in my iphone app. I am capturing image from camera and trying to match it with the stored image. My question is it possible to identify the image using CIDetector library. Please help if anyone knows :)

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

From `CIDetector.h`

```
// Types to be used for +[CIDetector detectorOfType:context:options:]

/* Specifies a detector type for face recognition. */
CORE_IMAGE_EXPORT NSString* const CIDetectorTypeFace __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_5_0);
```

Answer: no.

Comment: Hi Jimpic, thanks for your time. How can I match stored image with the new one? Where i could give the sample image reference?

Comment: There is no way doing this through CIDetector.